# std::string vs char[] vs char*

Tags: c++, string, std

I know this question was asked before, but everyone seems to have a different opinion about it. It's still very confusing, after reading SO posts too.

Bjarne Stroustrup, the creator of C++, recommends in his book to

> Prefer strings over C-style strings (a char*)

Many programmers these days still use char arrays and C style strings, despite `std::string` being more intuitive and usable. They say they don't need most of the functionality that `std::string` has.

But is it really **that** much overhead? This seems to be more relevant in games development, so does that mean that a lot more resources are needed for strings and that it could affect the frame rate?

Comment: Depends on context (including legacy code you have to work with). As you've already found out, there is no one definite answer. How much overhead it has and whether that's relevant is entirely situation-dependent.

Comment: It is still a valid question. The answer shall not be opinion based. It shall rather be experience based. It is ok to have an opinion without any experience, but sharing experience is even more important than sharing absolute truths than can be looked up in some document. Most difficult programming qusetions are context dependent I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is it really that much overhead?

No. In most cases, no. And with C++11's move-semantics, the number of cases (where it used to be overhead) has been greatly reduced. In most cases, people who *still* prefer `char*` do so, because of their ignorance. In some, *very very rare cases*, they may be right in choosing `char*` over `std::string`. I'm not counting the cases where you need to call C API, though in many cases you can still use `std::string` with C API, just use `c_str()` if the API takes `const char*`.

Sometime `std::string` may not be suitable, that doesn't mean `char*` is the next choice. No, it is not, because `std::vector<char>` can still be your choice. So you see, there are many choices in C++, before you choose `char*`.

Note that the number of cases (which is already rare) will be further reduced if the following proposal is accepted by C++ committee for C++1y (maybe, C++14):

- http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3334.html

Comment: And you can still use `std::string` for calling a C API (fully in C++11), so it's not that special.

Comment: @chris: Edited. I was too lazy to add that.

Answer (score 0):

Use std::string per default, but use char* where you need it performance. Can give several factors of speed up in the innermost loops.

Actually Bjarne also writes in the 3rd edition of The C++ Programming language that

istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n );

might be used to prioritize speed before interface. I.e. is is faster than:

istream& getline (istream& is, string& str, char delim);

Comment: Why would you care about a small performance difference right around a user input?

Comment: @Chris: User input? Is the question only about user input? Myself read drawings with millions of lines. I would like to add that the particular app has become a world success due to its speed. If I could downvote this comment I would do it several times. Need to get points :)

Comment: You're talking about one version of `getline` being faster than the other. It seems to make little difference when whatever speed difference there is becomes greatly outweighed by the input itself.

Comment: @Chris: Those who say that std::string shall and can be used instead of char* are correct as long as not performance measurements indicate that time is spent at e.g. string heap allocation. Having char[] buffer is simply faster. Of course it also depends on how you use std::string. Can't say whether C++11 changes this fact. But having spent decades I can just say that not agreeing with me shows inexperience.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not about std::string and char *, what I want to say is :

In fact, we should care about the heap-allocated char * or the char * inside std::string in critical path. in other words,  we should avoid dynamic memory allocation, std:string or char * is not the problem, they can be both slow enough if you do heap-alloc frequently in your code.